# Replace Response.Headers.Add with method attribute decorator

Tags: asp.net, controller, attributes, http-headers, decorator

In a Controller, I have this method:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> DownloadReportAsync()
{
    var file = GetFile();
    Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Content-Disposition");
    return File(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(file), "text/csv", "fileName");
}
```

Is there a way to replace the line `Response.Headers.Add()` with an attribute decorator on the method like `[ResponseHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Content-Disposition")]` to have a more clean code? I don't want middleware to apply to all requests. Just to some methods.

Tries:

1. I have found some document [Filters in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-6.0) but when I paste the attribute `[ResponseHeader(..)]`, it is unrecognized and no 'using' can be imported.
2. If I can create a custom attribute for a method. I would consider that a very nice solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to do it using [.NET Filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

**Filters/ResponseHeaderAttribute.cs**

```
public class ResponseHeaderAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly string _name;
    private readonly string _value;

    public ResponseHeaderAttribute(string name, string value) => (_name, _value) = (name, value);

    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext context)
    {
        context.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add(_name, _value);

        base.OnResultExecuting(context);
    }
}
```

**Controller.cs**

```
[ResponseHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Content-Disposition")]
public ActionResult Method() {}
```